# Connect Informix with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, informix

I have php 5.4 with codeigniter 3.1.9 installed on my windows 10.

I have suse linux 10 which has informix server.

I created odbc connectivity in my windows 10 client for informix link and i successfully connected and the production is running for the past couple of years.

I have many production applications running.

Now, I need to know how to download LARAVEL offline and install in my local windows 10 pc and make connection to the same informix database. (with existing odbc)

Comment: The download and install is probably trivial.  The configuration for an already working ODBC data source should also be fairly simple.  That said, I know not the details; I don't use Windows very often.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : What do you come to say ? Cannot understand.

Comment: You ask "What do you come to say?".  I'd have to answer: "Almost nothing".  I assume that there is a site from which binary distributions of Laravel can be obtained, and that the basic installation of the software is as straight-forward as any other package on Windows.  So, that's what the 'download and install is trivial' part means.  Configuration is another matter — I don't know what Laravel does, precisely, so I don't know how much configuration is required to get it to do what you want.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ However, if you have the ODBC connection working separately from Laravel (well done), then it ought to be straight-forward to tell Laravel to use that connection.  Having said all that, I've not tried it, so there are probably wrinkles that aren't obvious to me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, still can’t understand what you want to convey

Comment: I have no useful information to convey. Sorry!